# HP laptop + Windows 10 delayed sound when plugin in headphones

Tags: windows, windows-10, hp-envy

When I'm not using headphones, as soon as a I click play on any media (youtube, vlc, etc...) the sound of the media is not delayed

But when I plug my headphones, no matter the headphones, there is a 2 to 3 seconds delay before audio signal reaches the headphone. I hear la a little click and a white noise before I hear the sound

How can I fix it on my Windows 10 machine ?

I think the problem is described here with no apparent solution
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/Audio-delay-of-about-2-seconds-only-with-headphones/td-p/6649690

Could you guyz help solve it ?

Comment: You need to post the model of your headphone. Also did you update the drivers?

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς  Any headphone I plug in behaves the same. Whether it's iphone, boose, whatever... I also updated the drivers and WIndows 10 today

Comment: Then the problem is on your computer. Maybe its hardware.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς lol it's an HP Envy. That's sad lol. Thank you though

Comment: I guess you need to take it to repairs people, then.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Na I give up. There is no HP shop where I live so I'll bear with this slight inconvenience vs getting my PC completely ruined lol